# Error in date comparison

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the current date, reducing its months by 6 months, and checking whether in my database i have a date higher than the created date. However it's not working. What did i do wrong?

```
var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth()-5; 
                var yy = today.getFullYear();
                yy = yy.toString().substr(2,2);
                today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yy;

"END_DATE >="+today +"
```

this is a format of one of the dates stored in my database:
28-DEC-16

the variable today is giving me 26-6-15

Comment: Note that you can end up with invalid dates: like February 31, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i know the functionality still have lots of work, also regarding the year... do you know any similar working functionality out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things.

- Your logic is faulty. In January, `today.getMonth()-5` would yield `-5`, clearly not a valid month. To properly subtract an amount of months, try `today.setMonth(today.getMonth()-5)` - this will adjust the year as needed, however be aware that it may not behave as expected if, say, you subtract one month from March 31st (February 28th? 29th 2016? March 3rd? 2nd 2016???) - this is a general problem with date manipulations and more code will need to be written to handle such edge cases, but that's for you to decide how to handle.
- Months are zero-based, but you are putting them into a date string. Again using January as an example, this will result in `-00-` for the month part.
- You are not padding your numbers at all. This may or may not be an issue, but you probably want to add a zero to numbers less than 10 to ensure proper string length and easier comparisons.
- Your date format is bad. The correct format for dates is `Y-m-d`, for instance today is `2015-12-26`. Not only does this format reduce ambiguity, it is also sortable as a string without any effort involved. Consider using this format everywhere, and only format it as something else (eg. `d/M/Y` - `26/Dec/2015`) when presenting it to the user.
- You are putting a raw variable into a database query. This is bad for a number of reasons, you should be using parameters if possible, but at the very least you need quotes around your string (eg. `"END_DATE >= '"+today+"'"`). Otherwise, the query would literally read something like `"END_DATE >= 26-12-2015"`, which is equivalent to `"END_DATE >= -2001"` and is just as nonsensical.

I think that's all that I've spotted... Verdict: throw this code out and start over, keeping in mind all the things above.

Comment: thank you very much for your time..You clarified many things.